# How to create reactive provide/inject

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**note** version: `vuejs2` `composition api`

as shown in the below posted code, in the parent component, i `provide` the value of the reactive variable `status`. in `mounted` lifecycle callback i change the value of `status` every specific amount of time.
in the child component, i `inject` the value of `status` as demonstrated below in the code.

at run time, i expected that log statement in

```
watch:{
    injStatus(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log({msg:' watched injStatus. oldVal:' + oldVal + ', and newVal: ', newVal});
    },
  },
```

to be displayed with different values for the `status` variable, but that does not happen.

please let me know how to make `provid/inject` reactive

**url to attempts:**

[click here please](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-app-ywzajc?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2Fassets%2FInjectionKeys.js)

**parent**

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld></HelloWorld>
</template>
<script>
import {computed} from 'vue'
import {InjectionKeys} from './assets/InjectionKeys.js'
import {HelloWorld} from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
        return {
          status:undefined
        };
      },
    provide() {
        return {
            [InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS.description]: computed(() => this.compPropsStatus),
        };
    },
    computed:{
      compPropsStatus() {
        return this.status
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.status = '1'
        }, 1000);
      
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.status = '2'
        }, 3000);
      
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.status = '3'
        }, 5000);

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.status = '4'
        }, 7000);
    }
}
</script>
```

**child**:

```
<script>
import {InjectionKeys} from '../assets/InjectionKeys.js'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  inject: {
        injStatus: { from: InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS.description },
    },
  watch:{
    injStatus(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log({msg:' watched injStatus. oldVal:' + oldVal + ', and newVal: ', newVal});
    },
  },
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why does the question have 2 and 3 tags? Which version is it? This may work depending on it. I'm not totally sure what's going on here, since composition and options are mixed, this leaves you in undocumented zone. Try to make injStatus a deep watcher

Comment: @EstusFlask i added a note to the quest. please have a look. would you please point out where in the code i am mixing composition and options api?

Comment: See the docs  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch . `computed()` is composition. I'd expect it to be straightforward and worked as expected if you were using composition api only

Comment: @EstusFlask i used depp watch as mentioned in the question but it did not work-please see section attempt-to-solve-it. for computed, i replaced it with the following 'provide() {
      return {
          [InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS.description]: () => this.compPropsstate,
      };
  },'  but also did not work

Comment: Removing computed won't work because it stops being reactive this way. Try to switch to V2 specific way, `status: { value: null }` in data, `this.status.value = ...` to change it, `[InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS.description]: this.status` to provide. Then a deep watch or `'watch:{ 'injStatus.value': ...` may work.

Comment: @EstusFlask unfortunately it did not work either

Comment: Consider providing a demo so it could be debugged, this can help

Comment: @EstusFlask how can i make a demo please

Comment: @EstusFlask i added a link to stackbilz..pls have a look

Comment: It wasn't set up properly. The watcher itself is workable. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-app-1maohq . Notice that this is V3 which may work differently from your case. You need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Comment: @EstusFlask iam using vuejs3.would you pls tell how the code in the link you provided differs to the code I posted in stack blitz which is the link in my question?sorry I can’t discern the difference

Comment: HelloWorld wasn't correctly imported and not used at all, you can see that in the console

Comment: @EstusFlask good morning.would you please tell me if the way I declared constants is the recommended approach for declaring constants as shown in the url posted in my question? Also if post the answer to the question I will accept it because it is solved the problem.thanks

Comment: Yes, but a symbol is redundant, you're using a string as injection token any way.

Comment: Yes, but a symbol is redundant, and so is the whole InjectionKeys declaration. You're using a string as injection token any way.  Could be `export const PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS = 'PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS'`

Comment: @EstusFlask would you please tell me why ‚symbol‘ is redundant?

Comment: That's because you're using a string (description) already. Not a problem in your own app as there's no chance for accidental string collision.

Comment: @EstusFlask would you please have a look at this question if you have time?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77049660/v-model-returns-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options and composition API is combined, this may lead to the undetermined result. A is just reactive object with `value` property, can be created manually and then be passed by reference:

```
data: () => ({
  status: { value: null }
}),
provide() {
    return {
        PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS: this.status
    };
},
mounted() {
    this.status.value = 1;
    ...
```

In a child:

```
inject: {
    injStatus: { from: 'PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS' },
},
watch: { ['injStatus.value'](newVal, oldVal) {...}, ...
```

With composition API, this can be wrapped with composables:

```
const useProvideStatus = statusRef => provide('PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS', statusRef);

const useStatus = () => inject('PROVIDE_KEY_STATUS');
```