# V-Model returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I am using `vue3` with `options api`

as shown in the code posted below, in the `toggle-button` i have a `v-model` `vModelToggleDigitizePolygon`. each time the `toggle-button` is changed in state, the `onToggleBtnDigitizePolygonChanged` is called and the printed value of `vModelToggleDigitizePolygon`
is `undefined`

i expected, that every time `onToggleBtnDigitizePolygonChanged()` is called, the value of `vModelToggleDigitizePolygon` will be changed accordingle from `false` to `true` and conversly, but that does not happen

please let me know why the value of `vModelToggleDigitizePolygon` is always `undefined` and how to fix it

**code**

```
<template>
    <cds-toggle id="idToggleBtnDigitizePolygon" class="clsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon">
        <label for="toggling-digitization-of-polygon-on-and-off">
            {{ toggleBtnDigitizePolygonLabel }}
        </label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            :value="vModelToggleDigitizePolygon"
            @input="$emit('update:vModelToggleDigitizePolygon', $event.target.value)"
            :disabled="isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled"
            @change="onToggleBtnDigitizePolygonChanged()"
            :checked="isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonChecked"
        />
    </cds-toggle>
</template>

<script>
import ClsDigitizePolygonInteractions from '../../map/classes/PolygonDigitization/ClsDigitizePolygonInteractions.js'
import { SysConstants } from '../../map/assets/System/SysConstants.js';
import { DigitizePolygonConstants } from './resources/DigitizePolygonConstants.js';
import { InjectionKeys } from '../../map/assets/System/InjectionKeys.js';


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonCheckState: false,
        };
    },
    props: {
        toggleBtnDigitizePolygonLabel: {
            type: String,
            default:
                DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_TOGGLE_BUTTON_DIGITIZAE_POLYGON.description,
        },
        isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonChecked: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
    emits: ['update:vModelToggleDigitizePolygon'],
    computed: {
        vModelToggleDigitizePolygon: {
            get() {
                console.log(verboseTag, 'get.vModelToggleDigitizePolygon:' + this.vModelToggleDigitizePolygon);
                return this.vModelToggleDigitizePolygon;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log(verboseTag, 'set.vModelToggleDigitizePolygon:' + value);
                this.$emit('update:vModelToggleDigitizePolygon', value);
            },
        },
    },
    watch: {
        isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonCheckState(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonCheckState.oldVal:', oldVal);
            console.log('isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonCheckState.newVal:', newVal);
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onToggleBtnDigitizePolygonChanged() {
            console.info(infoTag, 'onToggleBtnDigitizePolygonChanged()');
            console.info(infoTag, '():', this.vModelToggleDigitizePolygon); //<== returns undefined
            
        },
    },
    created() {
        console.log(verboseTag, 'created()');
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's undefined because you don't set it anywhere, this.vModelToggleDigitizePolygon is returned inside vModelToggleDigitizePolygon, this could actually lead to infinite loop. It's done like the answer suggests indeed

Answer (score 1):

Use `modelValue` prop to pass `v-model` from the parent and `@change` event to properly upate the model value. Also use the `checked` property of the `checkbox` type input for the value propagation.

See [Demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Solution with minimal code:

```js
// ToggleInput.vue
<template>
    <label>
        {{ toggleBtnDigitizePolygonLabel }}
        <input type="checkbox" :value="modelValue"
            :disabled="isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled"
            @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.checked)"
            :checked="modelValue"
        >
    </label>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        modelValue: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        toggleBtnDigitizePolygonLabel: {
            type: String,
            default: "Default Label"
        },
        isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

And the usage as:

```js
// Parent.vue
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import ToggleButton from './ToggleInput.vue';
const toggle1 = ref(false)
const toggle2 = ref(true)
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <ToggleButton v-model="toggle1" />
    {{ toggle1 }}
    <br>
    <ToggleButton v-model="toggle2" toggleBtnDigitizePolygonLabel="Checked Label" />
    {{ toggle2 }}
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: hi. i think [@]change in your answer should be @input, am i right?

Comment: `input` can also be added with the same logic...should work fine as long as it emits `update:modelValue`

Comment: but as appears in my question, i want to use `vModelToggleDigitizePolygon` in `computed` object not in `props`

Comment: If you use it from computed, it would be complex to manipulate the input value from the parent component. How do you plan to use the `ToggleButton` component?